# Can't emit event from Express route in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I have set up socket.io (1.3.5) in my clustered express (4.11) app and have this working (in my main app.js file)

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    io.emit('message', 'ja');
});
```

This, console logs out in the browser and works fine. Here's what I want to do:

> I want to emit a message when an action has been performed on the server side, to notify the user that there is something new to see.

I am passing the io object in to my routes module, so that I have access to it within my routes.

When I try this:

```
router.post('/entries.json',(req, res, next) => {
    io.emit('message', 'nein')
});
```

I don't get any errors, it just fails silently. I feel like its something fairly fundamental that I'm just not seeing. What can I do to make this work?

Comment: What port are you running on? When launch your node.js app up, can you see it listening at the correct port (see the ref at the end) ? - http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-out-which-service-listening-specific-port/

Comment: I think you have to emit on connected socket object : `socket.emit` . See doc: http://socket.io/docs/

Comment: A long shot, but have you tried wrapping the `io.emit` in your route handler in a `io.on('connection', ..)` listener?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the wrong method, try this:

```
io.sockets.emit('message', 'nein');
```

Comment: Nope, don't need that

Answer (score 0):

It should be working that's weird, I have created an example that is working where you can see how I am using the io.emit method to send a message to all sockets connected:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // you can use io.sockets.emit or io.emit, it is the same.                                                                
    io.emit('message', 'there is something new');
    res.end();
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('new connection');
});

server.listen(4040, function() {
    console.log('server up and running at 4040 port');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to use [socket.io emitter](https://github.com/automattic/socket.io-emitter), I'm not sure if it was related to the fact that I was using clusters as well, but it works now!